# Generating a list of random values and printing them to standard output in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am pretty new to Haskell and I am struggling to achieve something relatively simple: to generate a list of random numbers and print them to standard output.

Since the random concept is pretty contrary to the function purity in FP world (i.e. methods should return always the same result for the same input), I understand that in this case, the `System.Random` module in Haskell returns IO actions instead.

My code so far looks like the following:

```
import System.Random

randomNumber :: (Random a) => (a, a) -> IO a
randomNumber (a,b) = randomRIO(a,b)

main :: IO ()
main = do
   points <- sequence (map (\n -> randomNumber ((-1.0), 1.0)) [1..10])
   print points
```

The idea is simple: to generate a list of ten random elements (probably there are better ways to achieve that). My first approach has been creating a function that returns a random number (`randomNumber` in this case, of type `IO a`) and using it when mapping over a list of elements (producing a list of IO actions, `IO [a]`).

From my understanding, `sequence (map (\n -> randomNumber ((-1.0), 1.0)) [1..10])` type is `IO [a]` but I do not know how I can use it. How can I really use points as some value of type `[a]` instead of `IO [a]`?

**EDIT: Adding the print function within the do "block" produces some errors I don't really know how to get rid of.**

```
Main.hs:8:40:
    No instance for (Random a0) arising from a use of ‘randomNumber’
    The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Random Bool -- Defined in ‘System.Random’
      instance Random Foreign.C.Types.CChar -- Defined in ‘System.Random’
      instance Random Foreign.C.Types.CDouble
        -- Defined in ‘System.Random’
      ...plus 33 others
    In the expression: randomNumber ((- 1.0), 1.0)
    In the first argument of ‘map’, namely
      ‘(\ n -> randomNumber ((- 1.0), 1.0))’
    In the first argument of ‘sequence’, namely
      ‘(map (\ n -> randomNumber ((- 1.0), 1.0)) [1 .. 10])’

Main.hs:8:55:
    No instance for (Num a0) arising from a use of syntactic negation
    The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Num Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
      instance Num Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
      instance Integral a => Num (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      ...plus 37 others
    In the expression: (- 1.0)
    In the first argument of ‘randomNumber’, namely ‘((- 1.0), 1.0)’
    In the expression: randomNumber ((- 1.0), 1.0)

Main.hs:8:56:
    No instance for (Fractional a0) arising from the literal ‘1.0’
    The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Fractional Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
      instance Fractional Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
      instance Integral a => Fractional (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      ...plus three others
    In the expression: 1.0
    In the expression: (- 1.0)
    In the first argument of ‘randomNumber’, namely ‘((- 1.0), 1.0)’

Main.hs:9:9:
    No instance for (Show a0) arising from a use of ‘print’
    The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    Relevant bindings include points :: [a0] (bound at Main.hs:8:9)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Show Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
      instance Show Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
      instance (Integral a, Show a) => Show (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      ...plus 65 others
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: print points
    In the expression:
      do { points <- sequence
                       (map (\ n -> randomNumber ((- 1.0), 1.0)) [1 .. 10]);
           print points }
    In an equation for ‘main’:
        main
          = do { points <- sequence
                             (map (\ n -> randomNumber ((- 1.0), 1.0)) [1 .. 10]);
                 print points }
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: By exactly what you did, i.e. binding the result with `<-` within the `do` notation of `IO` monad. Why don't you try `print points`?

Comment: The name `points` gets bound to a value of type `[a]` in this context, because `sequence ... [1..10]` has type `IO [a]`.  The `<-` or "bind" syntax can be thought of "extracting" a value from a monadic context.  Here, your context is `IO`, and your value has type `[a]`.

Comment: Also, it might make things look a bit nicer : `points <- replicateM 10 (randomRIO (-1,1))`. (`replicateM` being from `Control.Monad`).

Comment: `points` is already in scope as a value of type `[a]` for anything within that `do` block.  Try adding a `print points` statement immediately after your last line with the same indentation as `points <- ...`

Comment: I tried it before but I got some errors I didn't know how to fix, please see updated question.

Comment: @bartavelle I agree, didn't know of such method, thanks!

Comment: @jarandaf Write it as `points <- replicateM 10 (randomRIO (-1, 1 :: Double))`  The explicit type signature should help.

Comment: Thanks @bheklilr, that fixed the issue. I will take Zeta answer as the accepted one though, since it's more elaborated :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Why does this happen?

There is one particular message in all your errors: `The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous`. Why is this the case? Well, `randomNumber` works for any instance of `Random`, and there are a bunch of instances. `-1.0` includes `Num`, since you want to be able to negate a value. Also, the value `1.0` itself concludes that your type needs to be an instance of `Fractional`. That reduces the amount of types that can be used in this circumstance, but it's still not unique: `Float`, `Double` and four others are suitable.

At this point, the compiler gives up, and *you* need to tell it what instance you actually want to use.

### How to fix this

There are many ways to fix this. For one, we could introduce a small helper function:

```
-- fix a to double
randomDouble :: (Double, Double) -> IO Double
randomDouble = randomNumber
```

Or we could annotate the type of the ambiguous `1.0`:

```
points <- sequence (map (\n -> randomNumber ((-1.0), 1.0 :: Double)) [1..10])
--                                                   ^^^ as a Double
```

Or we could annotate the type of the list:

```
print (points :: [Double])
--     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  points is a list of Doubles
```

Which one you choose is actually more or less a matter of style and personal preference. That being said, `sequence . map f $ xs` can be written as `mapM f xs`, but since you actually have `IO a`, you're better of with `replicateM $ randomNumber (...)`. Both `mapM` and `replicateM` can be found in [`Control.Monad`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Monad.html).

### TL;DR

When GHC yells at you for ambiguous types, annotate them.

Comment: Thanks @Zeta for the explanation. I still need to get used to GHC compiler errors :)

Answer (score 3):

A couple points:

1. You called the function randomNumber, but allowed it to take any type that is a part of the Random class (including Chars etc.). If you do only want it to take numbers, you should change the signature to match its purpose (`randomNumber :: (Int,Int) -> IO Int)` or more generically, `randomNumber :: (Num n. Random n) => (n,n) -> IO n`
2. `sequence` takes a list of actions (`[IO a]`), and returns a list in the IO monad (`IO [a]`). It basically just executes each action, stores the result, then re-wraps the list in IO. You could try something like `replicateM 10 $ randomNumber (1,10)`. `replicateM` takes an Int and an action to carry out, and returns a list of executed actions (as Zeta pointed out, `sequence` is used internally in a call to `replicateM`).

(And code blocks aren't working for me for some reason, so I wrote everything as "infix code".)

Comment: Err, `replicateM :: Monad m => Int -> m a -> m [a]`, not `Int -> m a -> [m a]` (which is actually `replicate`). You're probably confusing `replicate` and `replicateM = sequence . replicate`. To get code blocks working in lists: indent them 6 (or more) spaces instead of 4.

Comment: Whoops, you're right. It returns sequenced results. I'll fix. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Carcigenicate for your answer. I will take Zeta's as the accepted one, since it seems more complete. In any case, thanks again for the help :)

Comment: Np. His is a better answer. Just thought if throw a couple things out there in case they helped.